# Python code for checking Legendre's conjecture over a range of numbers

Tags: python

I am tasked with implementing a function that takes in an input x and tests Legendre's conjecture (there is at least one prime number in range [n^2, (n + 1)^2] for every positive integer n) over a range of numbers from 1 up to input x.

This is the code I came up with

```
def legendre(x):

    q = 0
    for k in range(1,x+1):
        count = 0
        for i in range(k**2, ((k+1)**2)+1):
            deep_count = 0
            for j in range(2,i):
                if i%j == 0:
                    deep_count += 1
            if deep_count == 0:
                count += 1          #counts the number of primes within the range k^2 and (k+1)^2
        if count>=1:
            q += 1                  #counts that there is at least one prime in the range 1 and x
    return q == x
```

I believe the code works because I should be returning True for any input x. However the function takes a very long time to compute large numbers (eg. 500). How can this code be more efficient?

Comment: You should use a more effient way of testing primes, such as Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: You can break out of the loop as soon as you find a single factor, since it's not prime. You only need to test 2 and odd numbers. You only have to test up to sqrt(i).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#:~:text=9%20External%20links-,Simple%20methods,Otherwise%2C%20it%20is%20prime.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a prime generator and check the ranges of consecutive squares as you go.  When you find a prime within range n^2 and (n+1)^2, advance to the next value of n and check the subsequent primes against it.

The main issue with that approach is that it requires generation of primes up to (x+1)^2. This will work on relatively small values of x until it becomes too slow or fills up memory. Also, going through primes after having found one for a given range is unnecessary as we can skip to (n+1)^2 at that point.

Using a segmented sieve (movable sieve window), we can get a more optimal solution. If we generate a list of primes up to 1M, we can use it to quickly find a prime between n^2 and (n+1)^2 by regenerating the sieve bits starting at n^2.  Positions that are flagged in the sieve window are not primes. The other positions are potential primes and can be checked for primality much quicker.  This will greatly reduce the time it takes to find a prime between the two squares.

```
def legendre(x):
    # prepare for prime testing
    window  = min(10**6,(x+1)**2)   # sieve window size
    primes  = [2]
    isPrime = [True]*(window+1)     # sieve prime flags
    for p in range(3,window+1,2):
        if not isPrime[p]: continue # detect primes, and store them
        primes.append(p)
        isPrime[p*p::p] = (True for _ in range(p*p,window+1,p)) # flag multiples
        
    def checkPrime(N): # complementary prime check beyond initial window
        if N<=primes[-1]: return True
        return all(N%p for p in range(primes[-1]+2,int(N**0.5)+2,2))

    # progress through (n-1)^2 ... n^2 ranges           
    prime  = 3
    base   = 0
    n,n2   = 2,4
    while n<x:                       
        # advance sieve window as needed
        if prime >= base+window:     
            isPrime = [True]*window
            base    = prime
            for p in primes:
                offset = (p-base%p)%p
                isPrime[offset::p] = (False for _ in range(offset,len(isPrime),p))
        # find the next prime
        if not isPrime[prime-base] or not checkPrime(prime):
            prime += 2
            continue
        # if prime found before n^2, then range (n-1)^2...n^2 is valid,
        # then move on to next range, otherwise the conjecture is invalidated
        if prime>n2: return false 
        prime = n + 1 - (n&1)
        n,n2  = n+1,(n+1)**2
    # all ranges found a prime, conjecure is valid up to x
    return True
```

Test results:

```
from time import time

for i in range(3,9):        
    for x in (10**i//2,10**i):
       start = time()
       print(x,legendre(x),f"{time()-start:.4g} seconds")

500 True 0.1376 seconds
1000 True 0.5376 seconds
5000 True 0.5398 seconds
10000 True 0.5337 seconds
50000 True 0.5528 seconds
100000 True 0.6048 seconds
500000 True 0.8896 seconds
1000000 True 1.206 seconds
5000000 True 12.42 seconds
10000000 True 27.65 seconds
50000000 True 149.2 seconds
100000000 True 303.3 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a piece of cake - and I'm no Python expert. I notice that Stack indents Python when formatting as code. You will need to dedent it. (This code also uses a second method, explained https://qr.ae/pN0ywn, for estimating the prime count. You may ignore or just remove that. You will need to change the column labeling accordingly.)

```
# Author: Michael M. Ross, 2021 
 
def aprime(x): 
    if x == 2: 
        return True 
    for y in range(2, x - 1): 
        if x % y == 0:   
            return False   
    return True 
 
print("%-12s, %-12s, %-10s, %-10s, %-10s" % ("PS1", "PS2", "Interval", "Primes", "2*2...*p")) 
 
for n in range(1, 10000): 
 
    nc, pc, nx, tn, nl, txn, tnc = 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 
    ps1 = n ** 2 
    ps2 = (n + 1) ** 2 
    ni = (ps2 + 1) - (ps1 - 1) 
    iv = ni - 2 
    i = int (ni**(1/2) * 2) 
    n = n + 1 
 
    if ps1 % 2 == 0: tn = ps1 + 1 
    else: tn = ps1 
 
    for k in range(1, ni, 2): 
 
#Testing for primes in interval 
        if aprime(tn) is True: 
            pc = pc + 1 
        tn = tn + 2 
 
#Testing with parity in interval 
        txn = tn + 1 
        nx = 6 
        dc = True 
 
        for kk in range(i): 
            if txn % nx == 0: 
                dc = False 
                break 
            nx = nx + 4 
            if nx > i: 
                dc = True 
                break 
 
        if dc is True: 
            if txn % 4 == 0: 
                nc = nc + 1 
 
    print("%-12s, %-12s, %-10s, %-10s, %-10s" % (str(ps1), str(ps2), str(iv), str(pc), str(nc)))
```